# calculate dynamic zooming ng-map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

How can I dynamically calculate the zoom that is suitable for my map?
I want to use `setZoom(zoom)` but I don't want to add a fixed zoom for all maps, as I'm trying around , some zooms are just too zoomed for some cases and perfect for the others.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a set of coordinates that you need to be visible?

Comment: I do, and it's working well when I have multi markers they all appear using zoom-to-include-markers, the issue only appears when it's only one marker it's just too zoomed, and if I set the zoom to a static number let's say 15, this 15 is perfect for some cases and for somecases it needs more of zooming in like 20 . @antonio got me?